# What are Landau bands as opposed to Landau levels?

Tags: condensed-matter, terminology, quantum-hall-effect

I think, I understand what Landau levels are. They are quantized harmonic oscillator levels that arise when a bunch on noninteracting electrons are subjected to an external magnetic field. Can somebody please explain what the Landau bands are. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Landau levels are the energy levels which arise when an electron is subjected to a magnetic field and nothing else.  If you have a 2D gas of non-interacting electrons, then the Landau levels are the single particle energy levels.  The full Hamiltonian for the $N$-particle system would then feature a very large degeneracy for each energy.

In a real material, however, you will have disorder (impurities, lattice defects, etc) which can be modeled by adding a spatially random perturbation $V$ to the Hamiltonian.  These defects break the degeneracy which would be otherwise present, causing each Landau level to broaden into a band.  These are sometimes referred to as Landau bands.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. By the way, do you have the answer to the question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/572588/noninteracting-electrons-in-2d-in-presence-of-a-magnetic-field-and-a-periodic-po